# Visit a another external link in jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I open a jquery colorbox. The href takes me to a page which has a lot of external links to. I wish to be a able to click on the link and for the link to be open in the color box that is opened. Is that possible??

The link is a Facebook login.

Comment: Ricardo gave the correct answer.  I just want to add that some sites do not allow you to display them in an iframe.  I would assume that facebook would not allow you to iframe their pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look the site examples you'll see that it's possible to open it as an iframe.

```
$('#myLink').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
```

*References*:

- [Demos](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/)
- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox